# Как собрать bundle.css через webpack?

Tags: webpack

Есть проект на React. У каждого компонента есть css-файлы. Как через webpack 2 собрать все css-файлы в один общий bundle.css?

Вот такой конфиг почему-то не работает:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require ('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/client.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: 'public/js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    {
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: 'css-loader'
                    }
                )
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
    ]
};
```

Вообще ничего не создаёт.

Answer (score 2):

Сам возился в проблемой долго =)
Документация https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Там есть такая инфа:
It moves all the require("style.css")s in entry chunks into a separate single CSS file.

То есть необходимо подключить css-файлы через require или import(ES6) к точке входа `./app/client.js`. Либо создать вторую точку входа для css

Answer (score 0):

если Webpack 4 , то нужен "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
и нужно в точке входа index.js импортировать файл css

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import "../css/index.css";
```

webpack.config.js

```
"use strict";
const path = require("path");

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const paths = {
    DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/public"),
    SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    JS: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js"),
};

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: path.join(paths.JS, "index.js"),
    output: {
        path: paths.DIST,
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "babel-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
};
```